# How to *disable* natural scrolling?

Tags: gnome3, mouse

I can't disable natural scrolling. That is, **no matter whether I turn "Natural Scrolling" on or off,** dragging the mouse wheel towards me scrolls *up.*

[image: Mouse & Touchpad settings dialogue]

```
$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.20.4
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Fedora release 24 (Twenty Four)
```

No matter what I set it to, if I go back to all settings and then open the "Mouse & Touchpad" settings again, the on/off state is persisted. So it seems whatever state that is setting is not used by the mouse driver.

Comment: Just linking some related question: [Ubuntu Gnome](https://askubuntu.com/a/961704/830570)

Comment: You can consider [my answer there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707365/318461) - is it suitable to be posted here? [The solution you provided](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307929/318461) didn't work for me despite using x11.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/517202-Gnome-disable-natural-scrolling?s=ee2a83485dc84475bcc28ec774d32044&p=2774919#post2774919) worked for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll false
```

Comment: this is what I use to disable the so called "natural" scrolling. Just a heads up for if you want to script these `gsettings` commands (on the off chance you didn't know  this already) `gsettings` needs the full complement of environment variables to work. I think in particular `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and will fail if e.g. if you use `sudo` without the `-E` option

Comment: Thanks @the_velour_fog, I use [a Puppet module](https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-gnome) for that sort of thing.

Comment: This did not work for me. I can confirm the setting is set to `false`. I'm using Gnome 3.30.

Comment: Sorry to hear that @BenDavis. You should probably ask a new question, because that's probably a different bug.

Comment: @l0b0 I found out it was an issue with Wayland. I've since switched my session settings to use Xorg.